# Publishing multiple artifacts in a single package in jcenter does not work

Tags: android, maven, bintray, jcenter

How do I publish a package with multiple artifacts in `jcenter`?

Lets say I have a package

```
Group ID : com.package.mypackage
Artifact ID : myandroid-core-sdk
Version : 1.0.0
```

The above package is published and available in `jcenter` already.

Now, I wanna upload another artifact in the same package.

```
Group ID : com.package.mypackage
Artifact ID : myandroid-player-sdk
Version : 1.0.0
```

I am able to successfully upload this to `bintray` and I see the files there.However, in `jcenter` I only see the first artifact and not the second.

I know that this is possible, as other libraries like facebook have uploaded in a similar manner. Am I missing something?

Please help me with this.

Note : I am pretty sure there are no errors in the gradle files as the upload to bintray is successful and am able to use the library from those links.

Comment: The most important thing is that you have to change the version for each delivery...which you haven't done on based what you have written here...and that's the issue...

Comment: Hmmm...Actually both are 2 different libraries where we need to have similar versioning. Is that possible anyway?Also in future if we need to upgrade the library, what if the versions from different libraries clash in the same package?

Comment: Also I dont think that matters. Please check this link https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/. They have similar versions with different artifactIDs in the same package. Thats exactly what I want.

Comment: Ah sorry...misread there are different artifactId...than it should work...

Comment: Exactly. I am wondering what could be the reason. Also there is an open issue  https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin/issues/130 without a solution yet.